# RewriteRule Slash Single Redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a new redirect for my v2.2 api.php file. The desired link is: website.com/api/v2.2/ but rewrite just works if I use _ instead of /:

website.com/api_v2.2/ (WORKS):

```
RewriteRule ^api_v2.2/?$ /api.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

website.com/api/v2.2/ (DON'T WORKS):

```
RewriteRule ^api/v2.2/?$ /api.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Any idea?
I've tried these lines too, but nothing works:

```
RewriteRule ^api\/v2.2/?$ /api.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(api)/v2.2$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: did you try to add B flag ? RewriteRule ^api/v2.2/?$ /api.php [NC,QSA,L, B]  
documentation :http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: B Flag = 404 error too :/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the dot and slashes ?

```
RewriteRule ^api\/v2\.2\/?$ /api.php [NC,L]
```

The dot may cause problem here since it means "Any character" in the regex ([source](http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php)). Moreover, I don't think you need the `QSA` flag here.

Comment: 404 error too :/
/v2.2/ works fine but api/v2.2/ no :/

Comment: Well, it works when tested locally, `website.com/api/v2.2/` redirects to `website.com/api.php`, so there may be a problem with the rest of your `.htaccess`. Can you show us the whole file ?

Comment: I've tried with just:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #API
    RewriteRule ^api\/v2\.2\/?$ /api.php [NC,L]

Comment: Yes, **this works perfectly**. Your problem is elsewhere. What is the directory structure of your site ? Have you checked the file permissions ? Or your apache conf for this virtual host ?

Comment: With underline, works fine:

website.com/api_v2.2/ (WORKS):
RewriteRule ^api_v2.2/?$ /api.php [NC,QSA,L]

Comment: .htaccess and api.php is on the same home directory.

Comment: Well, it is weird. Please show us your apache error log to see what URL apache is trying to fetch when returning a 404

Comment: Follow the apache log, @tchap: 188.114.99.198 - - [23/Sep/2015:07:12:38 -0400] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 404 5559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.8 Safari/600.8.9"
188.114.99.198 - - [23/Sep/2015:07:12:39 -0400] "GET /api/v2.2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 5564 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.8 Safari/600.8.9"

Comment: Well, I give up - you have a problem with your global Apache conf or your file permissions. Check if Yosemite hasn't broken your conf http://www.thermalexposure.com/2014/11/14/fix-broken-apache-config-after-upgrading-to-os-x-yosemite/

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the website.com/api.php file to website.com/api/api.php
and the new .htaccess url rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^api/v2.2/?$ /api/api.php [NC,L]
```